# Visual Studio 2017 Preview - Can not create a Xamarin.Forms Application

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I am currently using this version of Visual Studio:

[image]

Whenever I try to create a Xamarin.Forms project I get the following error:
[image]

After I click the **Okay** button I get the following window which actually does not change anything:

[image]

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: It [looks like](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/164893/1560-create-xamarin-forms-solution.html) you can not use Visual Studio Preview. You can report this bug [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems the solution is to not use the preview version of Visual Studio, at least until the bug is resolved. Place to download the latest version is probably obvious, but in any case, it can be downloaded from [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/).